# Using pattern matching with result of net.liftweb.util.JSONParser.parse

Tags: json, scala, lift

I try to parse a JSON string with the net.liftweb.util.JSONParser. It's parse() method returns a Box[Any] value which I want to process via pattern matching like this:

```
JSONParser.parse("{foo: 'xxx', bar: 'yyy'}") match {
        case Full(Map) => println("ok")
        case x => println(x)
}
```

I'd expect this code to print "ok" but instead it prints

```
 Full(Map(foo -> xxx, bar -> yyy))
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
scala> import net.liftweb.util._
import net.liftweb.util._

scala> import net.liftweb.common.Full
import net.liftweb.common.Full

scala> JSONParser.parse("{foo: 'xxx', bar: 'yyy'}") match {
 | case Full(m: Map[_, _]) => println("ok")
 | case x => println(x)
 | }
ok

scala>
```

(I had forgotten the Full() around the Map[*,*]

I don't know your requirements, but Lift also has a another json library which is more powerful than JSONParser, it is called [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json)

Comment: This doesn't work either because JSONParser.parse() returns a Box[Any]. If that Box is not empty it will contain a Map. So I have to somehow match a Full(Map) - not just a Map.
My question is more related to the pattern matching that to the JSONParser.
I don't have any requirements regarding the JSON parser so I could probably get it working by using another one.
But I want to understand the pattern matching. I want to know why my approach doesn't work and how I should do it instead.

Comment: Updated with working code, you just missed [_,_] from your original match.

Answer (score 2):

`Full(Map)` means a `Full` containing the singleton `object Map`. If you want `Full` with something inside that is a Map (the object Map is not one), it should be `Full(m: Map)` (you can use `_` instead of `m` if you don't need access to that map)

Comment: Thanks four your hint. That makes total sense.
I have changed the case statement to 
    case Full(_: Map[_, _]) => println("ok")
but it still doesn't match the input. When I remove the _ from the Map I get a compiler warning because of Scala's type erasure.

Comment: I forgot the generic parameter, but I'm surprised that Full(m: Map[_, _]) does not work when Full(m: Map[String, Any]) does. Because it is supposed to do the same thing (which is why the compiler warns in the second case, it does not check the type parameters). Is it exactly what you did?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I finally figured out why it wasn't working for me: I had accidently imported `scala.collection.mutable.Map` by having `import scala.collection.mutable._` in my file. Now the Box which is returned by JSONParser.parse() contains `scala.collecion.immutable.Map`. That's why the pattern matching didn't work.